# Making A "Pyramid" or List of Lists From A List

Tags: python, algorithm

I was recently asked to build a pyramid structure from a list and came up with this solution.

For example, given a list of numbers from 1 to 10, the output would be:
`[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]`
It ultimately worked, but it seemed naive so I want to know if there is a more algorithmic/logical way to do this? My initial list is the `encoded_message.keys()` dict view.

```
    pyramid = []
    numbers = iter(sorted(encoded_message.keys()))
    i = 1
    go = True
    while go:
        row = []
        for row_length in range(i):
            try:
                row.append(next(numbers))
            except StopIteration:
                go = False
        if go:
            pyramid.append(row.copy())
            row.clear()
        i += 1
```

I got the desired result, but it doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: If your code works, you might want to check out [codereview.se].

Comment: Take a slice of length 1 from the list, then a slice of length 2, then a slice of length 3, etc etc.  Stop when there are no further elements in the list.

Comment: Should anyone be interested in a Ruby solution: `Enumerator.produce([1..1, 2]) { |r, i| [r.last+1..r.last+i, i.succ] }.take(5).map { |r,_| r.to_a } #=> [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]`. See [Enumerator::produce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-produce).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not fundamentally different from what OP does, but is spelt in a cleaner way using `itertools`.

```
from itertools import count, islice
def pyramid(diter):
    for i in count(1):
        res = list(islice(diter, i))
        if len(res) == i:
            yield res
        else:
            return

numbers = iter(sorted(encoded_message.keys()))
print(list(pyramid(numbers)))
```

Answer (score -1):

A function which uses `yield` to create a generator object and iteratively calculates each level of the triangle.

```
def triangle(lvls):
  lst = [1]
  for _ in range(lvls):
    yield lst  
    start = lst[-1] + 1
    lst = list(range(start, start + len(lst) + 1))
```

```
>>> list(triangle(5))
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

A nested list comprehension solution:

```
>>> [
...   [j for j in range(start, start + i + 1)]
...   for i in range(5)
...   for start in (i + 1 + sum(range(i)),)
... ]
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```